# Azure Bot Single Sign On between Single Page Application using authorization code flow

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

As per the Microsoft documentation, it is expecting us to use implicit flow for Single Sign On between Bot and Single Page Application. At the same time, Microsoft recommends us to move to auth code flow. Our client's Azure AD team is not allowing Implicit flow anymore. Can auth code flow work for SSO between SPA and Azure Bot?

Bot framework using implicit flow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots

Implicit flow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

Answer (score 0):

Create a bot application.

[image]

Go to ADD – App registration (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908)

[image]

Register one application

[image]

Go to Expose an API

[image]

Get the Application ID (Client ID)

[image]

Go to Expose an API

[image]

Paste the App ID and click on Save and Continue

[image]

[image]

Go to Client application and Click on Add a Client application

[image]

[image]

Go to Authentication and Click on Add a Platform

[image]

Click on Single page application.

[image]

Give the application redirection URI details.

[image]

Click on Configuration in Bot settings

[image]

Under configuration. Click on Add OAuth connection. Fill the required details.